# Converting Java to Symbian C/C++ - byte and  object array

Tags: java, c++, symbian, porting

Java code:

```
public static final byte cw_bArray = 0x01;
public static final byte cw_string = 0x02;

byte[] arr1=new byte[]{0x01};
byte[] arr2=new byte[]{0x02};
byte[] arr3=new byte[]{0x03};
byte[] code_ward_arr=new byte[]{cw_bArray,cw_string,cw_bArray};

method:
mount(null,new Object[]{arr1,arr2,arr3}, code_ward_arr);
```

I am trying to convert this code into symbian c/c++. I have done with this but i dont know how to pass argument anybody help me with this.

```
static const signed char cw_bArray = 0x01;
static const signed char cw_string = 0x02;

signed char a1 = {0x01};
signed char a2 = {0x02}; 
signed char a3 = {0x03}; 

signed char code_ward_arr[]  = {cw_bArray,cw_bArray,cw_bArray};
//signed char bbb[]  = {a1,a2,a3};  
   char *bb=new char[2];
    bb[0] = a1;
    bb[1] = a2;
    bb[2] = a3;

mount(NULL, bb[] , code_ward_arr);
```

method:

```
LOCAL_C void mount(signed char initData, char* obj[], signed char codeWord)
    {

    }
```

---

i am trying to convert this part of code to c
java code:

```
Object obj[] = null;
if(codeWord==null){
            obj = new Object[10];//Initial Loading Capacity
        }else{
            obj = new Object[codeWord.length];
        }
```

C code:

```
char* obj[] = {NULL};

 if(codeWord==NULL)
 {
 obj = new char[10];
 } 
 else 
 {
 obj = new char[Cwlen];
 }
```

i'll get this error
illegal operands 'char *[1]' = 'char *'

Comment: In C++, bytes are usually `unsigned char`.

Comment: not in Java, a byte is a signed char (-128-127). However I thought that char are naturally signed in C.

Comment: @poppy: Can you change `mount(signed char initData, char* obj[], signed char codeWord)` to `mount(unsigned char* initData, unsigned char obj[], unsigned char* codeWord)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
char a1[]={0x01};
char a2[]={0x01};
char a3[]={0x01};

char *  bb [3];
bb[0] = a1;
bb[1] = a2;
bb[2] = a3;


mount(NULL, bb , code_ward_arr);
```

Comment: Error :function call 'mount(int, {lval} char *, {lval} signed char[3])' does not match 
'mount(signed char, char **, signed char)'

Comment: see the link above. If you don't mind using c++ instead, I would go with the vector class.

Comment: @Jesse Good -  i changed but getting : expression syntax error

Comment: @Icfseth: in that link struct has been used without using that i cant pass?

Comment: Since c/c++ arrays are not bounded so i cant get the length of bb in that method. how to get length of char *  bb [5];??

Comment: usually I would always pass the size of an array with the array but it seems that using this simple method work: sizeof(bb)/sizeof(char *).

Comment: as you told for char* bb[5] it'll return 5 i.e correct,but for      char *bb=new char[2];                                            int bblen1 =  sizeof(bb)/sizeof(*bb); ->4
but it must return 3 right?

Comment: As I just said, it's better to pass the number of elements to the function. Less headaches :) I've never used this method before, so I don't know to what extent it is correct.

Comment: i am trying to create one global variable char * obj[] = {NULL}; and i want to resize at runtime so i used realloc-> obj =(char*)realloc(obj,Cwlen); but
getting this error 'char *[1]' = 'char *'

Comment: First, obj is not of tyoe (char *) but (char *[1]). Second, I'm not sure if you can resize an array of fixed size. Try to create obj dynamically from the beginning.

Comment: i am in confusion i am trying to create char* obj[] in this condition if(codeWord==NULL){ char* obj = new char[10];} else {char* obj = new char[Cwlen];} so if i want to use obj outside of if scope then i'll get undefined identifier 'obj' so i am trying to create global var and trying to resize but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The lines declaring `a1` to `a3` are wrong:

```
signed char a1 = {0x01};
```

This line declares a single character (byte) and then assign an array to it. Declare the variables as either arrays or as pointers:

```
// As array (my recommendation)
signed char a1[] = { 0x01 };

// As pointer
signed char *a1 = { 0x01 };
```

You also have to change the declaration of `bb`:

```
char *bb[] = { a1, a2, a3 };
```

I C++ arrays decay to pointers, so a pointer can be assigned to an array, but not the other way around.

Then you call `mount` without the brackets:

```
mount(NULL, bb, code_ward_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem here is `mount` is going to have no idea of the size of the arrays it is being passed. This isn't a problem for Java as its arrays contain additional meta data that C/C++ arrays do not (length being the useful one here).

There is a slight exception to this. C/C++ arrays (not pointers) have their size available at compile time, but only within the scope they were declared. One an array is passed as a pointer to another method the size of the array is lost.

To get around this problem you need to provide that additional length data. Perhaps the simplest, but most bulky solution is to place the data in a vector. This might be too heavy weight for you, especially if you are converting to C/C++ for efficiency reasons.

example:

```
vector<signed char> a1(1, 0x01); // create vector of size 1 with all elements 0x01
vector<signed char> a2(1, 0x02); 
vector<signed char> a3(1, 0x03); 

vector<signed char> code_ward_arr(3, cw_bArray);

vector<vector<signed char> > bb(3);
bb[0] = a1;
bb[1] = a2;
bb[2] = a3;

mount(NULL, bb , code_ward_arr);
```

method:

```
LOCAL_C void mount(signed char initData, vector<vector<signed char> >& obj,
        vector<signed char>& codeWord);
```

The lightweight solution is to either create a struct that holds a pointer to the data and a length of that data, or to simply add additional parameters to mount to hold the length of the arrays. This gets complicated and messy when you have arrays of arrays, so let's stick with the struct solution

eg.

```
template<typename T>
typedef struct array {
    size_t length;
    T* data;
} array;

LOCAL_C void mount(signed char initData, array<array<signed char> >& obj,
        array<signed char>& codeWord);

array<signed char> a1;
signed char a1_data[] = {0x01};
a1.length = sizeof(a1_data) / sizeof(signed char);
a1.data = a1_data;

...

array<signed char> bb_data[] = {a1, a2, a3};
array<array<signed char> > bb;
bb.length = sizeof(bb_data) / sizeof(array<signed char>);
bb.data = bb_data;

mount(NULL, bb, code_ward_arr);
```

You need to be careful though as the pointers inside the array structs are only valid for the duration of the method in which they were created (unless the actual arrays (`[]`) are global or created on the heap).